# How can I answer incoming Android phone calls in Ubuntu while still seeing their Caller ID?

Tags: 20.04, software-recommendation

I enjoy using Android Messages sending and receiving messages. But when my cell phone is in another room, I don't see when someone is calling me. How can I answer my cell phone through my computer? I have a disability and don't have my phone in my pocket. Can't always remember where it is.

Is there any application that enables me to answer phone calls it through my laptop?

Comment: changed the opinion to question, now what??

Comment: Made some more changes to your post, feel free to change it if you think it's too much. But my attempt is to make it less of an opinion-based and more of a software recommendation as I think that was your intention.

Comment: Thanks Dan!  With my brain disability I know What I Wanna say, but not always worded properly!  Thank you very much